# Why is my hard drive cycle count increasing so fast?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, smart

I would like to understand why SMART is reporting my HGST hard drive's load cycle count raw value as increasing, and if there is anything I should do to minimize this to extend the life of my hard drive.

I'm running Debian Jessie on my laptop, and I've been plugged-into A/C power for the past several hours. I have smartctl installed:

```
# apt-get install smartmontools
```

My hard drive is an HGST Travelstar:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
...
Model Family:     HGST Travelstar 7K1000
Device Model:     HGST HTS721010A9E630
...
```

I have a script periodically capturing some stats of interest:

```
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   089   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       5236
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1598
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   070   070   000    Old_age   Always       -       305107
```

My script is grabbing these values and storing them in a file so I can plot them over time with gnuplot:

```
Timestamp,PowerOnHoursValue,PowerOnHoursRawValue,PowerOnHoursWorst,PowerOnHoursThreshold,PowerCycleCountValue,PowerCycleCountRawValue,PowerCycleCountWorst,PowerCycleCountThreshold,LoadCycleCountValue,LoadCycleCountRawValue,LoadCycleCountWorst,LoadCycleCountThreshold
2017-06-10T11:02:18,089,5235,089,000,099,1598,099,000,070,304747,070,000
2017-06-10T11:17:01,089,5235,089,000,099,1598,099,000,070,304795,070,000
2017-06-10T12:17:01,089,5236,089,000,099,1598,099,000,070,305195,070,000
2017-06-10T12:27:03,089,5236,089,000,099,1598,099,000,070,305304,070,000
```

I have no `cmd_line` option set in my `/etc/hdparm.conf` file setting the `hdparm` option to configure the spin-down time; nor do I have any `-e apm` option set in my `/etc/smartd.conf` file.

I'm running MATE but I'm not sure if it has any configuration options set for the spin-down time other than the **Spin down hard disks when possible** checkbox under **System > Preferences > Power Management**. (By the way, it's currently unchecked when **On AC Power** and checked when **On Battery Power**.

From around 11:05 a.m. till around 12:00 p.m. I left my laptop alone but did not put it into standby or sleep; it was still on with the screen locked.

At 12:00 p.m. I started using it again and have been at the keyboard till 12:27 p.m.

Here are my current APM settings:

```
$ sudo smartctl --get=apm /dev/sda
...
APM level is:     128 (minimum power consumption without standby)

$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep level
    Advanced power management level: 128

$ sudo hdparm -B /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 APM_level  = 128
```

Per the description of the `-S` option to `hdparm`, 128 means the standby (spindown) timeout for the drive is 128*5=640 seconds, or just over 10 minutes, if I understood this correctly.

**Update:** I disabled APM on the drive by editing my `/etc/smartd.conf` and changing `-e apm,241` to `-e apm,off`, and then restarting smartmontools.

This looks like it helped stop the increase:

```
Timestamp,PowerOnHoursValue,PowerOnHoursRawValue,PowerOnHoursWorst,PowerOnHoursThreshold,PowerCycleCountValue,PowerCycleCountRawValue,PowerCycleCountWorst,PowerCycleCountThreshold,LoadCycleCountValue,LoadCycleCountRawValue,LoadCycleCountWorst,LoadCycleCountThreshold
2017-06-10T11:02:18,089,5235,089,000,099,1598,099,000,070,304747,070,000
2017-06-10T11:17:01,089,5235,089,000,099,1598,099,000,070,304795,070,000
2017-06-10T12:17:01,089,5236,089,000,099,1598,099,000,070,305195,070,000
2017-06-10T12:27:03,089,5236,089,000,099,1598,099,000,070,305304,070,000
2017-06-10T13:17:01,089,5237,089,000,099,1598,099,000,070,305585,070,000
2017-06-10T14:17:01,089,5238,089,000,099,1599,099,000,070,305864,070,000
2017-06-10T14:59:17,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T14:59:24,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T15:00:05,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T15:01:06,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T15:02:08,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T15:03:09,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T15:04:10,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T15:05:11,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T15:05:26,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T15:15:27,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T15:17:01,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
```

If no one has any better ideas, the next thing I can try is playing around with the 241 value to see how that makes a difference. According to the `hdparm` man page:

- **0**: timeouts are disabled
- **1..240**: multiples of 5 seconds, yielding timeouts 5s..20m
- **241..251**: 1..11 units of 30 minutes, yielding timeouts 30m..5.5h
- **252**: 21-minute timeout
- **253**: vendor-defined timeout period 8h..12h
- **254**: reserved
- **255**: 21-min plus 15-sec

I wanted 241 for my laptop specifically for a 30-minute timeout, so I would expect the load cycle count to increment by 1 no less than every 30 minutes; however, it appears I was seeing counts increase 300-400 times per hour before I disabled APM, which would average to 5-7 times per minute, or once every 8-12 seconds.

Please correct me if I'm interpreting these incorrectly.

**Update:** I just picked up the laptop and took it out of Suspend. In the last update, I never examined the APM level after restarting `smartmontools`. I'll do that this time.

Since coming out of Suspend, I noticed my cycle count only increased by 1 this time since my laptop went into Suspend and now came out of Suspend:

```
...
2017-06-10T15:17:01,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T15:25:28,089,5238,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-10T15:35:29,089,5239,089,000,099,1600,099,000,070,305868,070,000
2017-06-11T00:56:09,089,5239,089,000,099,1601,099,000,070,305869,070,000
2017-06-11T01:04:24,089,5239,089,000,099,1601,099,000,070,305869,070,000
...
```

What's funny is now it kept increasing again:

```
...
2017-06-11T01:04:24,089,5239,089,000,099,1601,099,000,070,305869,070,000
2017-06-11T01:14:25,089,5239,089,000,099,1601,099,000,070,305918,070,000
2017-06-11T01:17:01,089,5239,089,000,099,1601,099,000,070,305918,070,000
2017-06-11T01:21:35,089,5239,089,000,099,1601,099,000,070,305918,070,000
2017-06-11T01:24:26,089,5239,089,000,099,1601,099,000,070,305918,070,000
2017-06-11T01:33:48,089,5239,089,000,099,1601,099,000,070,305963,070,000
```

I checked the APM level and it's back to 128:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep level
    Advanced power management level: 128
$ sudo smartctl --get=apm /dev/sda
...
APM level is:     128 (minimum power consumption without standby)
$ sudo hdparm -B /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 APM_level  = 128
```

My `/etc/smartd.conf` settings still specified `-e apm,off` so I simply restarted `smartmontools` and then checked the APM level again:

```
$ sudo service smartmontools restart
$ sudo smartctl --get=apm /dev/sda
...
APM feature is:   Disabled
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep level
    Advanced power management level: disabled
$ sudo hdparm -B /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 APM_level  = off
```

I purposely put the laptop into Suspend again and took it back out. I checked the APM level and it was 128 again just like above; when I restarted `smartmontools`, the APM level again was disabled just like above.

Again my cycle count is holding after disabling APM:

```
...
2017-06-11T01:33:48,089,5239,089,000,099,1601,099,000,070,305963,070,000
2017-06-11T01:34:27,089,5239,089,000,099,1601,099,000,070,305971,070,000
2017-06-11T01:42:06,089,5239,089,000,099,1601,099,000,070,306048,070,000
2017-06-11T01:42:58,089,5239,089,000,099,1602,099,000,070,306050,070,000
2017-06-11T01:43:24,089,5239,089,000,099,1602,099,000,070,306050,070,000
2017-06-11T01:44:32,089,5239,089,000,099,1602,099,000,070,306050,070,000
2017-06-11T01:45:00,089,5239,089,000,099,1602,099,000,070,306050,070,000
```

Following information in [Bug #1248012](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdparm/+bug/1248012), I tried enabling the APM options in `/etc/hdparm.conf`:

```
...
# -B apm setting
#apm = 255
apm = 255
# -B apm setting when on battery
#apm_battery = 127
apm_battery = 255
...
```

I restarted `hdparm`:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/hdparm restart
```

After putting the hard drive into Suspend and bringing it back out, I noticed the APM level is back to 128.

I opened [Question #1218107](https://superuser.com/questions/1218107/laptop-apm-level-gets-reset-when-coming-out-of-suspend) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values you got from `man hdparm` apply to `-S` option – spin-down, making platters stop rotating.

My quick research indicates that `Load_Cycle_Count` is connected to parking heads and it seems the `-B` option (Advanced Power Management, APM) is the right one. The description in the man page is not perfectly clear to me but your value of `128` is the *most aggressive* one that doesn't permit spin-down. My guess is it parks the heads most often.

You calculate a spin-down time from this value of `128` using the description of `-S` and I think it's wrong. This calculation confuses `-B` and `-S`. The same confusion occurs when you set APM to `241`.

I've seen [claims](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1565889&p=11678807#post11678807) that `hdparm -B 255 /dev/sdX` helps. It disables Advanced Power Management though. My disk is set to `254` and it has what I think is a moderate `Load_Cycle_Count` with respect to `Power_On_Hours`: 200k and 20k respectively, so the ratio is way better than yours.

My advice is to use *one* of the following:

```
hdparm -B 127 /dev/sdX
hdparm -B 254 /dev/sdX
hdparm -B 255 /dev/sdX
```

I guess if you set `-B` to a value that permits spin-down (i.e `127` or less) then you should also adjust `-S` option to get not-too-short spin-down time. This is because every spin-down requires heads to be parked.

While `man hdparm` warns about various dangerous options, `-B` is not among them. Even if I'm completely wrong it should be safe to experiment.

Comment: I tried both 127 and 255 manually as specified above for the -B option; both are keeping the load cycle count steady. The only problem remaining now is why it keeps getting reset, for which I opened a separate question as described in my edit above.